# Adjusting a regex config file in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am working on this regex:

```
$regex = '~\\'.$var.'\s+=\s+\''.$oldval.'\';~is';
```

This is full code function

```
function write_value_of($var,$oldval,$newval, $file)
{
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $regex = '~\\'.$var.'\s+=\s+\''.$oldval.'\';~is';
    $contents = preg_replace($regex, "$var = '$newval';", $contents);
    file_put_contents($file, $contents);
}
```

^ that regex use for config like :

```
$database = 'stats';
$eCoin = '1';
```

but my config like this:

```
database = stats
eCoin = 1
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php might be more suitable than regex.

Comment: thanks, but i have some reason why i choose that
,could u help me change that?

Comment: @PutraFajarHasanuddin: What? Can you rephrase your question? Why can't you use `parse_ini_file()`?

Comment: some like this: bot_virtualhostname = |c00FF3366VIVA , bot_commandtrigger = !

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be:

```
^([^\s]+)\s+=\s+([^\s]+)$
```

I modified your function as below:

```
function write_value_of($var,$oldval,$newval, $file)
{
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $regex = "/^{$var}\s+=\s+{$oldval}$/m";
    $contents = preg_replace($regex, "$var = '$newval';", $contents);
    file_put_contents($file, $contents);
}
```